# A question about convergence of improper parametric integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

Could you give me some hint how to find all $\alpha\in R$ for with the integral $\int_0^1 \frac{a-x^{\alpha}}{1-x}$ converges. Is clear that this integral converges for all$\alpha\in N$, but I could not understand how to deal in case $\alpha \notin N$.

Thanks.

Comment: For $a=1$, this becomes the formula for generalized [harmonic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).

Comment: O, that is very beautiful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By change of variable $t=1-x$ the integral becomes:

$$\int_0^1\frac{a-(1-t)^\alpha}{t}dt$$
and clearly if $a\ne1$ then
$$\frac{a-(1-t)^\alpha}{t}\sim_0\frac{a-1}{t}$$
so the integral is divergent. Now let $\boxed{a=1}$ then
$$\frac{a-(1-t)^\alpha}{t}\sim_0 \frac{\alpha t}{t}=\alpha$$
so the function can be extended by continuity on $0$ and then the integral is convergent.